# QGIS assigning accumulating numbers to field records following order of selection using @rownum

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, select-by-attribute

I have selected points in QGIS and they have a field (`towerno`).

This filed represents values in the range from 658 to 800 but I want to narrow it from 558 to 700.

[image: selected points in Attribute Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the column `towerno` via the fieldcalculator using `"towerno" - 100`.

Comment: Technically, *narrowing* the range would mean raising the floor or lowering the ceiling, eg changing 658-800 to 758-800 or 658-700. This formula reduces all the values by a fixed amount. However, that seems to be what the original poster was asking for.